# How does XNA's KeyboardState represent all keyboards?

Tags: xna, keyboard

I already understand how to work with `Keyboard` and `KeyboardState`, but when debugging I happened to take a look at the `KeyboardState`'s non-public members via the VS debugger. I expected to see a large list of values, but instead, only saw 8 **uint**s at a static level, and another 8 **uint**s per instance:

```
Non-Public members  (static)
    stateMask0  uint    976757505
    stateMask1  uint    67108863
    stateMask2  uint    3221225470
    stateMask3  uint    4294967295
    stateMask4  uint    196863
    stateMask5  uint    4244635647
    stateMask6  uint    4160752641
    stateMask7  uint    1876688932

Non-Public members  (instance)
    currentState0   uint    0
    currentState1   uint    0
    currentState2   uint    0
    currentState3   uint    1048576
    currentState4   uint    0
    currentState5   uint    0
    currentState6   uint    0
    currentState7   uint    0
```

There are 32 bits per **uint**, so having 8 of them essentially acts as a field of 256 boolean values, which loosely corresponds with the `Keys` enum type, so I *assume* that the static values act as a way to test which buttons are present on a device. However, XNA supports up to 4 keyboards, so I'm not sure how it both translates this to a button state, nor how it can differentiate between different keyboards in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XNA only supports one *keyboard*. It supports up to four *chatpads*, which look exactly like keyboards in terms of the state they track (note the subtle differences in the overloads of [`Keyboard.GetState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.keyboard.getstate.aspx)).

Anyhow, `KeyboardState` object *just* reflects the state of a keyboard or chatpad. On its own, it doesn't know or care about whether or not it's representing the state of the keyboard or the state of a particular player's chatpad, or what.

When you call the [`GetState` overload that takes a player index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975640.aspx), the `Keyboard` interface can kill out the `KeyboardState` with the appropriate bits for the specified player at that point, so `KeyboardState` itself only needs enough storage to represent a single keyboard state.